# JS on page load debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

A form field with the ID of mainSearch gets focus when the page loads. I am struggling to debug this and find out where that gets set in the source code. Is there a way I can debug this element to see how it is getting focus?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to make element autofocused.

1. HTML only: Just place `autofocus` attribute.
2. JS: Use `element.focus()`.

So, if I were you, I'll search for `.focus()` in sources.
Then, make several break points nearby.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of :focus-visible pseudo-class applies while an element matches the :focus .
i also suffered many time with this,then I try

```css
*:focus-visible{
 outline:none!important;
/* your style */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
console.log(getEventListeners(document.getElementById("mainSearch")));
```

Comment: This looks promising but nothing comes up. I am looking in the console log on FF

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getEventListeners is not defined

Comment: I tried in chrome, anyway if you can't find it, you could `blur()` on `focus()` (just once)